# How to split time records across midnight in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, timestamp

For example, if I have the following data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Start': ['2022-01-01 08:30:00', '2022-01-01 13:00:00', '2022-01-02 22:00:00'],
                   'Stop': ['2022-01-01 12:00:00', '2022-01-02 10:30:00', '2022-01-04 8:00:00']})
df = df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

                Start                Stop
0 2022-01-01 08:30:00 2022-01-01 12:00:00
1 2022-01-01 13:00:00 2022-01-02 10:30:00
2 2022-01-02 22:00:00 2022-01-04 08:00:00
```

How can I split each record across midnight and upsample my data, so it looks like this:

```
                Start                Stop
0 2022-01-01 08:30:00 2022-01-01 12:00:00
1 2022-01-01 13:00:00 2022-01-02 00:00:00
2 2022-01-02 00:00:00 2022-01-02 10:30:00
3 2022-01-02 22:00:00 2022-01-03 00:00:00
4 2022-01-03 00:00:00 2022-01-04 00:00:00
5 2022-01-04 00:00:00 2022-01-04 08:00:00
```

I want to calculate the duration per day for each time record using `df['Stop'] - df['Start']`. Maybe there is another way to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could start by implementing a function that computes all dates splits from each row :

```
from datetime import timedelta


def split_date(start, stop):                                                                        
                                                                                                
    # Same day case                                                                                 
    if start.date() == stop.date():                                                                 
        return [(start, stop)]                                                                      
                                                                                                
                                                                                                
    # Several days split case                                                                       
    stop_split = start.replace(hour=0, minute=0, second=0) + timedelta(days=1)                      
    return [(start, stop_split)] + split_date(stop_split, stop)
```

Then you can just use your existing dataframe to create a new one with all records by computing the split of each record :

```
new_dates = [
    elt for _, row in df.iterrows() for elt in split_date(row["Start"], row["Stop"])
]      
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_dates, columns=["Start", "Stop"])
```

Then the output should be the one you expected :

```
                Start                Stop
0 2022-01-01 08:30:00 2022-01-01 12:00:00
1 2022-01-01 13:00:00 2022-01-02 00:00:00
2 2022-01-02 00:00:00 2022-01-02 10:30:00
3 2022-01-02 22:00:00 2022-01-03 00:00:00
4 2022-01-03 00:00:00 2022-01-04 00:00:00
5 2022-01-04 00:00:00 2022-01-04 08:00:00
```